# Unblocking accept()

Tags: windows, sockets

I have a blocking call to accept(). From another thread I close the socket, hoping that it'll unblock the accept() call, which it does but I have a case when it doesn't: e.g. thread A enters accept(), thread B closes the socket, thread A doesn't return from accept().

Question: what could cause closing a socket to not unblock an accept()?

Comment: So it works, except when it doesn't?  I don't understand how your first description (which succeeds) differs from your second description (which fails).

Comment: How certain are you? I suggest creating a small program that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Robert, I don't know what's the difference but yes, in a simple test program it works then later on in a more complicated program it doesn't. I do know for sure though that 1) the socket is closed and 2) an accept on the same socket isn't returning. So I was asking if someone knows when this could happen.

Answer (score 2):

One hacky trick to unblock `accept(2)` is to actually `connect(2)` to the listening end from your other thread. Flip some flag indicating it's time to stop the loop, `connect(2)`, `close(2)` the connecting socket. That way the `accept(2)`-ing thread would know to close the socket and shut itself down.

Answer (score 1):

You must not ever free a resource in one thread while another thread is or might be using it. You will **never** get this to work reliably. For one thing, you can never be 100% sure the thread is actually blocked in `accept`, as opposed to about to block in it. So there will always be race conditions.

And, of course, `shutdown` won't work because the socket is not connected.

There are a couple of ways to handle this problem. For example, you can set a flag that the thread checks when it returns from `accept` and then make a connection yourself. That will cause the thread to return from `accept` and then it will see the flag and terminate.

You can also switch to non-blocking sockets. Have the thread call `select` or `poll` with a timeout and check if the thread should terminate when it returns from `select` or `poll`. You can also `select` or `poll` on both the socket and a pipe. Then just send a byte on the pipe to unblock the thread. `pthread_kill` is another possibility, as is `pthread_cancel`.

Not knowing the details of your problem, my guess would be the best solution is to rearchitect so you don't have a thread whose sole job is to wait forever in `accept`. That way, you won't even have a thread you need to kill. If you don't want to keep accepting connections, just rig things so that your threads stop doing that, but let the threads keep going doing other things. (The number of running threads you have should be dependent on the number of things you can usefully do at once, not the total number of things you have to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `shutdown()` followed by `close()` from thread **B**. You should be checking the return codes on these calls too as they may help you figure out what is going wrong when thread **A** fails to become unblocked.

Comment: Calling shutdown() doesn't help (not surprisingly, if called, it returns WSAENOTCONN). Calling closesocket(), with or without having called shutdown(), succeeds. I've verified that the handle being closed is the same one that hangs in the accept() call. No luck.